# Top 3 results from 4+ tables

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to:

For each player get their result from each event listed in the events_table and show the total from their best 3 results so:

John id=1 played all and scored 16,11,12,4 so top 3 = 39

What is the easiest way to get this data?

**Player_table**

```
id  /   name
------------
1   /   john
2   /   sam
3   /   bill
4   /   joe
```

**Events_table**

```
id  /   date
------------------
1   /   01/03/2012
2   /   04/04/2012
3   /   06/06/2012
4   /   08/08/2012
```

**event_id_1_results_table**

```
player_id   /   score
---------------------
1           /   12
3           /   16
0           /   11
0           /   8
```

**event_id_2_results_table**

```
player_id   /   score
---------------------
1           /   16
2           /   14
3           /   11
0           /   14
```

**event_id_3_results_table**

```
player_id   /   score
---------------------
1           /   8
3           /   12
4           /   13
0           /   18
```

**event_id_4_results_table**

```
player_id   /   score
---------------------
2           /   6
3           /   4
4           /   9
0           /   7
```

Comment: why do you keep different events in different tables? it would be easier to keep 1 table for all events and introduce a eventId column

Comment: If you control the tables, merge the different tables and add an extra column "event_id". This will avoid all the [`Unions`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) and make it easier to add new events to your application. That being said, you can solve this with a subquery.

Comment: I thought it would keep the queries on each event quicker, after a lot of events a combined table would get very big.

Comment: I recommend to redesign your database structure first. What about when you have e.g. 40 events after 2 years? 40 different tables with same fields on each? And you will extend this type of queries (which you are looking for now) for each new event?

Comment: Due to the feedback I'm going to look at changing the database structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need or want to keep the different tables, use a union:

```
select sum(score)
from ((select score from event_id_1_results_table where player_id = 1)
       union
       (select score from event_id_2_results_table where player_id = 1)
       union
       (select score from event_id_3_results_table where player_id = 1)
       order by score desc limit 3)
```

Comment: Thank you Olaf, I'll try that also

Comment: Ok I had a play with this and with a quick edit it does what I need for now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you *have to* use this database structure.

First you should get the events in the `$events` variable, then generate the result query with the event ids, like this:

```
$results = array();
$event_joins = array();
foreach ($events as $v) {
   // eX.score AS eX_score
   $results[] = "e".$v['id'].".score AS e".$v['id']."_score"; 
   // LEFT JOIN event_id_X_results_table AS eX ON eX.player_id = Pt.id
   $event_joins = " LEFT JOIN event_id_".$v['id']."_results_table AS e".$v['id']."
                    ON e".$v['id'].".player_id = Pt.id ";
}
$qs = "SELECT Pt.*, 
      ".implode(",", $results)."
      FROM Player_table AS Pt
      ".implode("", $event_joins);
```

The query generated above would result a table like:

```
id / name / e1_score / e2_score / e3_score / e4_score
-----------------------------------------------------
 1 / john /       12 /       16 /        8 /     NULL
 2 / sam  /     NULL /       14 /     NULL /        6
 3 / bill /       16 /       11 /       12 /        4
 4 / joe  /     NULL /     NULL /       13 /        9
```

Using this result you can determine the 3 highest score for each player and sum them up.

Depending on the number of events this could end in really <strike>ugly</strike> large joined queries since all the event results are in separate tables, so I would seriously recommend **rethinking the database structure** if you have control over it.

Comment: Thank you aorcsik, I'll have a try with that. I do have control of the database so will look at changing it to 1 table with event id's